# Since computers don't have cd-rw drives anymore

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, dvd-burning

Since computers don't have *CD-RW* drives anymore,
can I still play and burn *CD-R* or *CD-RW* disk with a *DVD-RW* drive?
The file types are mostly wav or mp3 files.

Comment: Are you sure this is your only use case? What about ripping audio CDs?

Comment: What do you mean by 'play / burn' files? Are you trying to create a disk that can be used in a traditional CD player?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. DVD-RW drives are backwards compatible with CD-R, CD-RW, and DVD-R media.

Comment: Personally, I'd look for the respective logos if I had a particular product on my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely

Any DVD-RW drive is backwards compatible with CD-R / CD-RW disks.

Just make sure you tell the software you're using (which should not have changed since the CD-R / CD-RW days) that you want to create an audio disk.

Comment: Ehm... I'm not so sure that the OP would create an audio disk...

Comment: As I read it, the Q is about writing digital audio WAV/mp3 files to data discs. Why do you suggest to create audio discs, where error correction is lousy?

Comment: The OP says they want to 'play / burn' files. No way to play a file unless it is audio. Granted the question's clarity should be better.

Comment: One can't play WAV/mp3 _files_ from audio CDs, so even though the Q could benefit from some clarification, I don't see much need for your somewhat adventurous assumption. ;)

Comment: Thing is, the OP clearly thinks playing and burning a file have two different meanings from their point of view. So even though you are technically correct, calling this an assumption is far fetched! Have added a comment to the question in attempt to make sure the OP's question is answered... which is why we're here!

Comment: @ClassStacker... Ehm (Again ehm... :-) )... in some (old) CD models were possible to play the audiocd without using the computer at all, it was not needed at all (!!!) (it was possible to use a power supply and the headphones). This was made to save the few resources available on the computers at that time. There was even a special cable to bring audio from cd to the soundcard. (Archeology I suppose...) Honestly I never tried to use this feature on a dvd reader.

Comment: @Hastur Not sure I get your point. I personally always connect the drive's audio output to the mainboard when I assemble PCs. But the Q contains `wav` and `mp3` which are digital audio formats not found on audio CDs, no?

Comment: The OP states his source files are in WAV / MP3 format. He says nothing about them needing to be in any format once burned to the disk. Just because they are files pre-burning doesn't mean he wants them to stay in the same format after burning

Comment: Gotcha! He didn't mention any format conversion. And yes **the quesition is bad written.** BTW It's possible to have some CD with mp3 and/or wav files and it is possible that you may  want to play other audio CD, with no need to convert anything or without excluding the possibility to do it. It's possible to have a mixed cd with audio and data tracks too. Sadly we don't know what is in Ratiug's mind; good luck with the questions you did in the comment: this is a not registered user that had his own answer...I suppose that if you change ") that you want" in ") when you want" you'll have more +.

Comment: @DavidVernon Yes I was assuming too, as I wrote in my above comment: Personally, I'd not want to make audio CDs from mp3s because that would mean reducing quality twice due to the lousy error correction during audio CD playback. But YMMV and while this is an interesting discussion, we may have lost the OP already. ;)

Comment: Ok it was easy to miss the weight of the word __Mostly __ mp3 and wav files... that I cannot quantify even now... :-)  @ClassStacker Not only to the motherboard often directly to the [audio card](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/243968-28-cdrom-audio-cable)...

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Look for data-sheet for specific DVD-RW drive and media compatibility chart.
Drives have internal database of manufactured media (with laser power calibration, some drives have "learning capability"). I didn't had any problems in the past with any drive media combination but there is never 100% warranty.

If drive is old and you are using newly created CD-R's - burn might be inferior quality due to lack of laser calibration info.
To check burn quality use https://qpxtool.sourceforge.io/ (if your drive has this capability).